Why isn't continuity necessary for existance of partial derivatives?
Consider the graph of a function.
$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{x^2+2y^2},  & \text{(x,y) $\neq$ (0,0)} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$
It is discontinuous at $(0,0)$. As on path $y = mx$, the function evaluates to $\frac{m}{1+2m^2}$ limit depends on the path and hence is not continuous.
But its partial derivatives exist at $(0,0)$.
What's the difference between derivates and partial derivates that gave rise to this situation? Isn't a partial derivative much like a derivate of a 3D curve in a plane? Even the procedure to find PD becomes the same once we consider other variables constant.

But $f(x,y)$ is continuous in each variable separately. Why should a partial derivative care about joint continuity? A partial derivative is the derivative of the function of one variable which you get by fixing the values of the other variables.

Partial derivatives are specific examples of what are known as directional derivatives.
The directional derivative of $f$ along the line spanned by the unit vector $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{R}^2$, at the point $\mathbf{0}$ is given by
$$\nabla_{\mathbf{v}}f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{0}+h\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{0})}{h}$$
Hence choosing $\mathbf{v} = (1,0)$ we recover the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ at the point $(0,0)$. Then it becomes clear why partial derivatives do not need continuity of the function to be defined, they are essentially path-limits themselves, and as long as the function is continuous and differentiable along a particular straight line, its directional derivative in the direction of a unit vector that spans that line, will exist. In your example, $f$ is $0$ on both axes, the constant $0$ function from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is certainly differentiable, hence the directional derivatives along the axes, or the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$, exist.
